# Play Audio in Sencha app with external url

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-2.1

I am new to sencha and I am trying to add audio player to my app, where  the url for audio is an external link. here is the code I used

```
{
            xtype:'audio',
            url:'http://dl.enjoypur.vc/upload_file/5570/6757/%20Bollywood%20Hindi%20Mp3%20Songs%202015/Prem%20Ratan%20Dhan%20Payo%20(2015)%20Mp3%20Songs/02%20Prem%20Ratan%20Dhan%20Payo%20%28Title%20Song%29%20Palak%20Muchhal%20-%20190Kbps.mp3',
            title:'Sample MP3',
            thumb:'media/sample.jpg'
        },
```

App shows me a audio player in view, but that is just unresponsive and doesn't play. is there a way to insert audio from external link?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be really helpfull if you share more of your code in matter to find the bug. Well this works for me:

```
Ext.create('Ext.Container', {
fullscreen: true,
layout: {
    type: 'vbox',
    pack: 'center'
},
items: [
    {
        xtype : 'toolbar',
        docked: 'top',
        title : 'Ext.Audio'
    },
    {
        xtype: 'toolbar',
        docked: 'bottom',
        defaults: {
            xtype: 'button',
            handler: function() {
                var container = this.getParent().getParent(),
                    // use ComponentQuery to get the audio component (using its xtype)
                    audio = container.down('audio');

                audio.toggle();
                this.setText(audio.isPlaying() ? 'Pause' : 'Play');
            }
        },
        items: [
            { text: 'Play', flex: 1 }
        ]
    },
    {
        html: 'Hidden audio!',
        styleHtmlContent: true
    },
    {
        xtype : 'audio',
        hidden: true,
        url   : 'http://dl.enjoypur.vc/upload_file/5570/6757/%20Bollywood%20Hindi%20Mp3%20Songs%202015/Prem%20Ratan%20Dhan%20Payo%20(2015)%20Mp3%20Songs/02%20Prem%20Ratan%20Dhan%20Payo%20%28Title%20Song%29%20Palak%20Muchhal%20-%20190Kbps.mp3'
    }]
});
```

Also I highly recommend the Touch [documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.4/2.4.2-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.Audio-cfg-url) with examples 
Tested within [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#home). Pretty nice music. I like this Oriental type of music. I hope it helps you :-)

Comment: I am trying to embed this in my app: http://www.shouthost.com/freeflashplayer/player/player.swf?file=http://123.176.41.8:8356/;listen.mp3&amp    but nothing is showing up in my view when I use 'xtype: audio'